# PySpark read data from MySQL

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I learning Spark using PySpark. I have a task to read data from MySQL.
Let me explain my hardware.
I have server with 64 RAM and 8vCPU.
I'm trying to read the table whose size is 180GB.
When I'm trig print 5 rows I have next error:

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "refresh progress"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "RemoteBlock-temp-file-clean-thread"
Exception in thread "Spark Context Cleaner" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "executor-kill-mark-cleanup" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "executor-heartbeater" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

This is my code

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("PySpark MySQL Connection") \
    .config("spark.jars", "/opt/spark/jars/mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory","50g") \
    .master("local") \
    .getOrCreate()


df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name") \
    .option("driver", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver") \
    .option("dbtable", "table_name") \
    .option("user", "user") \
    .option("password", "password") \
    .load()

df.show(5)
```

Comment: what 64 RAM? GB, MB? Also, try to add `df.limit(5)` or `df.first(5)` to your Spark statement.